# Adding a counter column in pd.DataFrame that resets based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas

In short, I need to add a column that continues to count up until a new game is listed in the dataframe. Here is a snippet of the pd.DataFrame, df.

Month  Year       Game  Earnings

```
  7  2017       ARMS   1195.00

  8  2017       ARMS     91.00
```

9  2017       ARMS     50.00

10  2017       ARMS    261.00

11  2017       ARMS    695.00

...     ...   ...        ...       ...

8  2021  rFactor 2   6647.79

9  2021  rFactor 2  27021.02

10  2021  rFactor 2  21020.26

11  2021  rFactor 2  11865.00

12  2021  rFactor 2    359.95

I can't figure out how to use df.loc[] to conditionally add a counter, more specifically, how to check if the next row != the current row.

This is what I have so far... I know it probably has to do with the if statement.

```
counter = 0

def update_month_counter(row):
    global counter
    for game in range(0, len(df)):
        if df.loc[game, df['Game']] != df.loc[game+1, df['Game']]:
            counter = 1
        else:
            counter += 1
    return counter 

df["MonthCounter"] = df.apply(update_month_counter, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Any help?

(ps. the dataframe has already been grouped by the game and sorted by the month and year).

Comment: can you share an example of the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want using [.cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)

```
df["Count"] = df.groupby("Game").cumcount() + 1
print(df)

   Month  Year     Game  Earnings  Count
0      7  2017     ARMS   1195.00      1
1      8  2017     ARMS     91.00      2
2      9  2017     ARMS    261.00      3
3     10  2021  rFactor   6647.79      1
4     11  2021  rFactor  27021.02      2
5     12  2021  rFactor  21020.26      3
```